# Repeat function while checkbox is active

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a Website that pings an API to receive images. Now I want to add a Checkbox which when pressed executes the function `apiping()` every 5 or so seconds as long as the checkbox is active. When the Checkbox isn't activate nothing should happen.

Edit (because im a fricking idiot):
I have already tried the whole setInterval onClick stuff. For Example, if Checkbox is activate `var interval = setInterval(apiping(),5000);` and when the Checkbox is not activate `clearInterval(interval);`. That worked except the clearInterval part which didn't work.

Edit 2:
Here is function apiping:

```js
      let url = 'https://nekos.life/api/neko';
      function apiping(){
        fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((out) => {
        console.log('Checkout this JSON! ', out.neko);
        imglink = out.neko
        document.getElementById("img").src = out.neko;
        document.getElementById("imgbig").src = out.neko;
        })
        .catch(err => { throw err });
      }
      apiping();
```

**SOLUTION**

```js
       var interval;

        function TryApiPing() {
          x = document.getElementById("slideshow").checked;
          if (x) {
            //makemagichappen
            interval = setInterval(apiping, 2000);
          } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
        }
```

This works. Thanks to everyone helping :D

Comment: Look in to `onClick` functions and [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="TryApiPing()" id="foo"/>
```

```
var interval;
TryApiPing() {
x = document.getElementById("foo").checked;
  if (x)
  {
    //makemagichappen
    interval = setInterval(apiping,5000);
  }
  else {clearInterval(interval);}
}
```

Sorry I'm not in front of my computer so the formatting might not be perfect but this function executes on click and checks the 'checked' property of the checkbox.  Inside of the if decision, you can use interval and the other code to make sure it happens repeatedly.  If the button is checked off, the function should call again and stop.

Comment: You never assign the result of `setInterval()` to the `interval` variable.

Comment: Just write `if (x)`

Comment: Sorry, Copy / Paste cut off part of his command.  I have updated accordingly.

Comment: `interval` needs to be a global variable.

Comment: Use the snippet editor, it has a Tidy button to fix the code formatting.

Comment: appreciate it :) But somehow it only "pings" the function apiping() once

Comment: @JonasAlpha could you show us what the apiping function looks like right now?

Comment: Use `interval = setInterval(apiping,5000);`, It shouldn't have function brackets`()`, [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) expects a reference to a function.

Comment: I've updated the Post with the function aswell a Gist of the whole website

Comment: Okay so it works.. kinda.. I'm having the same Issue again where clearInterval doesn't seem to work. It keeps pinging the API

Comment: NVM. Working now. Updated the Original Post with the working code